# Reasonable disk activity at idle?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I've been troubleshooting performance issues on a new Windows 10 build and wondering if anyone can give input on whether this looks like reasonable OS disk activity at idle. Chrome + Resource Monitor running in FG, OS is disk 4.

[image]

Comment: W10 is a very busy OS, its constantly doing housekeeping and sending telemetry data to Microsoft.

Comment: I suggest you help us by specifying: What exactly is your performance issue? What are you build specs? (CPU, HDD/SSD, etc.) Any reason to suspect performance issue is related to your disk activity?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be normal.

Lots of reads are done in Explorer of image files in the Recycle Bin,
probably for creating thumbnails for displaying the images as icons.

I have no explanation as to why the Recycle Bin is being viewed in Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from very slow response time to certain user input. Eg: opening programs, allowing admin access for apps and using search would have a very long delay. (This is compared to a few days ago when everything ran quickly). The only activity that appeared to be spiking was HD, so I assumed it was related to that. There was no obvious connection between recently installed software or any other changes to the slow down.

Upon further investigation, my slow down appears to have been related to Malwarebytes. Shutting that software down has brought me back to speed. Even though I had installed MWB right after Windows and had been running it for a week with no issues, somehow something  turned it ugly.

I am running: Ryzen 3900x / 64GB 3600 G-Skill Trident-Z Neo / RTX 2070S / OS Drive: Samsung 970 Evo Plus Nvme.

Anyhow, thanks for the input people. I am a recent Mac refugee and appreciate the help getting to know my new OS.